# How can i access a Custom Object that i have declared in a servlet class, in the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an instance of an object (Model which has got an ArrayList) in the servlet class, how can i access this in the "jsp" page using EL ?

This is how i am trying

```
<c:forEach var="module" items="${model}">
    <option name="" value="">${module}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Also it would be very wise to acquaint yourself with as much material as possible at [coreservlets.com](http://coreservlets.com). The section you experience problems with now is [Integrating Servlets and JSP: MVC approach](http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/csajsp2/14-MVC.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather that putting the data in session, in case it is a per-view data, pass it as request attribute in servlet's method:

```
request.setAttribute("model", yourModelObject);
```

This way it will be accessible in jsp as:

```
${model.yourList}
```

Your iteration will become:

```
<c:forEach var="module" items="${model.yourList}">
    ${module}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to iterate over your arrayList ?
you could do that with c:forEach tag

```
 <c:forEach var="box" items="${**REFERENCE_TO_YOUR_VARIABLE**}"
  varStatus="status">
 </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dispatching from the servlet with RequestDispatcher.forward(request, response), you might want to add it as a request attribute instead of a session attribute, to prevent stale instances of the object, and prevent the object from hanging around for longer than needed. As for the second part of your question.
If the ArrayList is a variable of the model object, referencing it in el is done as:

```
${model.list}
```

so, for instance, if the object is stored as a request attribute named "model", and the object has a getList() method, to iterate that list, do:

```
<c:forEach items="${model.list}" var="listItem" >
```